# selectOneMenu inside panelGrid -> row height too big

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a ui-composition containing a form containing a panelGrid. The panelGrid has 7 rows with 4 columns each. The last row contains in the second column a selectOneMenu.
It was requested to adjust the row height to 22px. Every element in the cells is 21px or less. Firebug shows me, that the selectOneMenu is 21px high als well. But somehow the row will be 25px high. The only css change I found out, that will change this, is setting the height of the inner label of the selectOneMenu from 15px to 12px. But this is no solution, since every input has the inner height of 15px.

```
<p:row>
<p:column styleClass="columnLabel">
<p:outputLabel value="#{msgs.inv_sum_assignment}" />
</p:column>
<p:column>
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="assign" disabled="#{summaryBean.noInvoiceSelected}" value="#{summaryBean.assignedUser}" converter="vertreterConverter" immediate="true">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" />
<f:selectItems value="#{summaryBean.possibleAssignments}" var="vertreter" itemLabel="#{vertreter.lastname}, #{vertreter.firstname}" itemValue="#{vetreter}" />
<p:ajax event="change" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>  
...
```

screenshot of the cell with the selectOneMenu
[image: screenshot of the cell with the selectOneMenu]
Tr style
[image: Tr style]
selectOneMenu Layout
[image: selectOneMenu Layout]
Tr layout
[image: Tr layout]

Can you help me, getting the row height to 22px or is that not possible?

I'm using:
primefaces version 6.1
com.sun.faces jsf version 2.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not completely sure, why, but now the line height works. Maybe it's because I changed the trigger size. Not sure though. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:panelGrid columnClasses="rowHeight">
```

In your CSS at the end:

```
.rowHeight {
    height: 22px;
    max-height: 22px;
}
```

To force it:

```
.rowHeight {
    height: 22px !important;
    max-height: 22px !important;
}
```

If this still doesn't work, you need to go to every element in the panelGrid and remove margin and padding.

If this still doesn't work, it means you customized one of your elements in the panelGrid with a specific height and will need to find witch one ;)

Once it works you can try to remove the max-height and !important. Then you will find the culprit

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But neither columnClasses nor rowClasses seem to have an effect on the generated html. =/